# Compiler not binding to correct generic method overload

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, type-inference, overloading

Usually, the C# compiler is smart about method binding and type argument inference.  But I seem to have stumped it.

```
class Obj
{
    void Handler( int a, int b ) { }

    Obj() { Method( "", Handler ); }

    public void Method<T>( T t, Action<T> action ) { }

    public void Method<T, U>( T t, Action<U, U> action ) { }
}
```

The `Method` call results in the compiler error:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'`.

Why doesn't the compiler notice that the call fits the second overload? I'm able to compile it by making the call more explicit as in `Method<string, int>( "", Handler )` or `Method( "", (Action<int, int>)Handler )`. But why is this necessary?

Comment: As a test, eliminate the first overload with Action<T>. You still do not compile, so let's forget overloading for a second. Focus on the algorithm for type inference and method group conversions. If you care to follow through, you may find section 7.5.2 if the C# language specification interesting.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take Anthony's suggestion and just consider:

```
class Obj
{
    void Handler( int a, int b ) { }
    Obj() { Method( "", Handler ); }
    public void Method<T, U>( T t, Action<U, U> action ) { }
}
```

Overload resolution fails. Why?  Well, we must infer T and U. Clearly T is string. What is U?

This bit is important: we deduce what U is *after we know what Handler is*.  Now, you might say that we know what Handler is because there's only one thing it could be.  But there is no rule of C# that says that if there's only one method in a method group that it automatically wins the overload resolution game. The rule is that the meaning of Handler is determined by running *overload resolution* on the method group associated with Handler. Overload resolution considers *arguments* and we don't have any arguments for Handler because the only argument list we could possibly have is (U, U), and U is what we're trying to determine in the first place.

So overload resolution fails here.  Now, if we had:

```
class Obj
{
    double M(string s) { }
    Obj() { Method( "", M ); }
    public void Method<T, U>(T t, Func<T, U> f) { }
}
```

That works fine. We infer T is string, and now we can do overload resolution on M, determine that M means `double M(string s)`, and now we know that U is double.

Comment: This helped me understand the issue more clearly, thanks.  Too bad the compiler isn't just a little bit smarter.  It would make the method I wrote much more concise to use.